# Is is ever appropriate to put functionality in a DTO?

Tags: language-agnostic, design-patterns, dto

Is it ever appropriate to put functionality other than basic setters and getters in a DTO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in a number of scenarios you may well need some serialization code (for whatever serialization interfaces your serializer API demands - things like `IXmlSerializable` / `ISerializable` in .NET), but I guess that isn't what you mean...

It really depends on the scenario. If you have an object model that is simple enough to *allow* you to use your domain model for serialization, then for small projects there may be little benefit in splitting it out - a separation of concerns issue? Probably. Going to cause long-term pain? Probably not (at least, not if you use a contract-based serializer, so you can swap it without anyone noticing).

For more complex models, you often will need a separate DTO model to the domain model - in which case you might need somewhere to put the conversion logic (methods / operators / etc) between domain and DTO - so *that* might live in there, but if you *have* got a separate DTO it is unlikely to have much *additional* logic - that logic belongs mainly in the domain model and the other business classes.

Answer (score 0):

By definition a DTO does not have any behavior, except for its data accessors. If you need some logic in them is likely that you need some refactoring your model.

Comment: Say I take a `Candy` as a parameter for my ASP.net webmethod. Can't I add a `SaveToDb` method to him? What would be the best practice? Prefer Composition over Inheritance?